# Separate my ActionListener from my GUI class, doesn't work properly

Tags: java, class, loops, user-interface

This is how my code looked in the beginning: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8270001
Now I removed the `ActionListener` to a separate class: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8257038

The program should give me a little UI, but it just keeps running without any UI popup or errors.

Someone told me this:

> In your GUI class constructor, you are creating a new `nupuVajutus` object, but since `nupuVajutus` extends the GUI class, when you create a `nupuVajutus`, you are also inherently calling the GUI class constructor by default, thus creating an infinite loop

If this is really the problem, then I have to say I am not that good and could use some help getting this program working with the classes separated.

Comment: Try posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) It seems like this issue could easily be replicated into a smaller example program.

Answer (score 3):

You have indeed already been given the answer, although what you have is not an infinite loop, but infinite recursion, which will eventually cause a StackOverflowError.

Here's what happens:

`new GUI()` calls `new nupuVajutus()`.  This creates a new `nupuVajutus` object by calling its constructor.  Because `nupuVajutus` extends `GUI`, this means a `nupuVajutus` object is a `GUI` object with additional functionality.  Therefore, because it is a `GUI` object, a `GUI` constructor needs to be called.  The `nupuVajutus` constructor does not explicitly call a `super` constructor, so it implicitly calls the `GUI()` (no argument) constructor before executing.  In this new call to the `GUI()` constructor, another `new nupuVajutus()` call is encountered, and so on, *ad infinitum*...

It seems to me you need to do some more research around Object Oriented Programming, in particular the topics of sub-classing, inheritance, object instances, and encapsulation.  There are [plenty of resources available to help you](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=inheritance+in+java).

After you extracted your ActionListener into a separate file, you should not have changed it to extend GUI.  That extends the **class** (which is like a blueprint) not an **instance** (which is like a something built using that blueprint) - remember: you can create multiple instances of a class.

Previously, the "nupuVajutus" ActionListener was an inner class, so it had access to all of the enclosing class' fields and methods.  Now that it is no longer an inner class, it needs to be passed a reference to the GUI instance so that it can access its methods.  Something like this:

```
public class NupuVajutus implements ActionListener {
    private final GUI gui;

    public NupuVajutus(GUI gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // The GUI instance can now be accessed through the gui field, for example:
        gui.something();
        // ...
    }
}
```

And in the `GUI()` constructor:

```
NupuVajutus nV = new NupuVajutus(this);
```

To be honest, though, there is nothing wrong with keeping your ActionListener as an inner class.  If you're never going to use that class outside of the GUI class, then it is probably preferable for it to remain as an inner class.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing it extending the GUI class. This **Does Not** make then share the **Same Fields** Say you have a field `field` in your GUI class

```
public class GUI {
    String field = "Hello";
}
```

Just because your Listener class `extends GUI` doesn't mean they will share the *exact* same `field` object. I think that's what you think is supposed to occur

```
public class Listener extends GUI implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        field = "World";
    }
}
```

The above does nothing the `field` in `GUI`. If you were to do this, you would need to access in a static way like line `GUI.field = "World";`.  The above is also what causes in an infinite loop, as you need to instantiate the `Listener` in the `GUI` class. This is not really good practice or design.

- One option would to use some sort of MVC pattern.
- Another option would be to pass the values you need, to a constructor in your `Listener` class, and instantiate it in your GUI class with those values.

---

Run this example to see what I'm talking about. I have a `MyListener` class that I pass a `Jlabel` to, the same `JLabel` in the GUI class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FieldTest {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel(" ");
    private JButton button = new JButton("Set Text");

    public FieldTest() {
        MyListener listener = new MyListener(label);
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FieldTest();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyListener implements ActionListener {
    JLabel label;

    public MyListener(JLabel label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        label.setText("Hello, FieldTest!");

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 to you, too.  Pretty much the same approach as mine, but this has a narrower scope (which may actually be preferable, from a design perspective, as it explicitly states which components the ActionListener is going to have control over).